# Converting picked date time dialog picker to store in sqlite DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created a DatePicker within my app. But the problem I am trying to overcome is how to take the picked date and store it in my database:
In my DB, the date field is set to TEXT

```
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        //Get the date
        if (v == buttonDatePicker) {


            mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                            etDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + month + "-" + year);
                            mYear = year;
                            mMonth = month;
                            mDay = dayOfMonth;
                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();

        }
        //Get the time
        if (v == buttonTimePicker) {

            mHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                            etTime.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                            mHour = hourOfDay;
                            mMinute = minute;
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, true);
            timePickerDialog.show();

        }
    }
```

I tried to convert the picked Year etc from int to String but it does not seem to like it when I tried to cast it.

How I am trying to store it in my DB :

```
        typedUpSmsMessage = smsMessage.getText().toString();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("textMessage", typedUpSmsMessage);
        cv.put("dateToSendText",mYear + mMonth + mDay);
        cv.put("gameID", gameID);
        automateGameDB.insert("automateGames", null, cv);
```

But ofcourse since the date is in int, it just adds the numbers.
Need to convert them into a string, or a date format? (yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the field is Text you should use `cv.put("dateToSendText", year + "-" + month + "-" + dayOfMonth)` with 4 digit year and 2 digit month and dayOfMonth, because it is comparable and sortable.

Answer (score 0):

Really don't understand your requirement. 
Will this code 
`String string = Integer.toString(int);` or `String.valueOf(int)` or simply `string+""`
solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Insert your date in database like

```
cv.put("dateToSendText",dayOfMonth + "-" + month + "-" + year)
```

or

```
 cv.put("dateToSendText",etTime.gettext().tostring());
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to store Date as a timestamp in your database :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
Long timestamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis() // Save timestamp in database
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 inputDate = mYear +"-"+ mMonth +"-"+ mDay;
 SimpleDateFormat src = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
 SimpleDateFormat dest = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
 Date date = null;
 try {
     date = src.parse(inputDate);
 } catch (ParseException e) {
     Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
 }
 String formattedDate = dest.format(date);
```

You can change dest Dateformat as u want...
Use 'TEXT' datatype in sqlite to store this date field